# Raise gaussian integer to gaussian integer power

Tags: number-theory, multiplication

Gaussian integer is a complex number whose real and imaginary parts are both integers.

Say I want raise $(a + b*i)$ to power $(c + d*i)$ and have result modulo $m$.

I can do it with floating-point approximation using normal complex power, as defined with exp and ln. But this is not precise, I can lost important last digits and this make result with small $m$ utterly wrong.

Is there an algorithm like Ancient Egyptian multiplication generalized for gaussian integers and for raising to power instead of multiplication to effectively obtain exact answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the result is transcendental, so no.

E.g., $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't think about that, though I knew it. Now I recognize that was pretty dumb question =)